# Hashmap in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hashmap, perl-module

I am writing a client API in Perl using FRONTIER::CLIENT module. I am trying to do similar like the following in Perl:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> message = (HashMap<Integer, String>)client.execute("APIWrapper.login"); 
System.out.println(message.get(1000));
```

How do I implement the same idea in Perl?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hashmaps are a native perl data structure.  Any variable declared with the hash symbol % is a hash storing key value pairs.  See this documentation on [Perl data types](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html).  Also see the [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

*Edit*

[See this example](http://www.ideone.com/5w3nU)

```
# This can be anything which returns pairs of strings
my %login_message = getData(); # ( 'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2' ); 

for my $key ( keys %login_message ) { 
        print "key: $key, value: $login_message{$key}\n"; 
}

sub getData {
        return ( 'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2' );
}
```

Outputs:

```
key: key2, value: value2
key: key1, value: value1
```

Comment: I came up with the below, but I got this exception:  "WANTED DATA, GOT TAG VALUE. my %login_message = {$server->call("APIWrapper.loginRequest")};

while ( (my $key, my $value) = each %login_message )
{
  print "key: $key, value: $login_message{$key}\n";
}

Comment: This is what I came up with:                                          my %login_message = ( $server->call("APIWrapper.loginRequest", @credentials) ); 
 
for my $key ( keys %login_message ) { 
        print "key: $key, value: $login_message{$key}\n"; 
}   AND the output still remain the same : WANTED DATA, GOT TAG 'VALUE'

Comment: @Gruther, Your error "WANTED DATA, GOT TAG 'VALUE'" is not an internal Perl error message. Look at the documentation for your call to `$server->call(...)` and see if it has information on its errors. For Perl's internal errors you can use the [perldiag](http://p3rl.org/perldiag) man page.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try as much as possible to explain further;

$server->call("Wrapper.loginRequest", @credentials);

This method (Wrapper.loginRequest) is returning a hashmap key, value pair. This is a java example of what am trying to achieve in Perl:

Comment: Object [] params2 = new Object[]{new String("admin"),new String("admin")}; HashMap<Integer, String> result = (HashMap<Integer, String>)client.execute("Wrapper.loginRequest",params2); System.out.println(result.get(1000));

Answer (score 4):

The following code is an example of using a hash in Perl:

```
my %data = (
    red => 1,
    blue => 37,
    green => 99,
);

print $data{'red'}, "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your posts. I managed to fix the bug. The problem was in frontier module. I switched to XML::RPC::FAST and all seem fine.

Why is integer not taking more than 9 characters. Can I find Long integers in Perl or Bigint something along those lines?